# Как парсить canvas объект

Tags: python, парсер

На сайте 1xbet, после выбранной игры можно выбрать событие в некой «таблице» и поставить ставку. Эта таблица с кнопками отображается как canvas. Как можно на питоне реализовать поиск кнопки Тотал 10.5М на 2 ой сет? Работал на selenium

Comment: Canvas - это HTML элемент

Comment: Я знаю, не получается его спарсить и нажать на кнопку в этом элементе